# Ms Access Syntax issues

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

My problem is that I would like to realize this, but it throws syntax error.

```
WorkDayUltimate: Format(DateAdd("mm/dd/yy","h",-6,[Outgoing Date])
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first add to date, then format:

```
WorkDayUltimate: Format(DateAdd("h",-6,[Outgoing Date]),"mm/dd/yy")
```